# how to load jquery in hangouts app (in xml file) for making some ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I want to make some ajax calls from the hangouts app, so I want to include jquery. But includinbg js file like  http://mywebsitecom/jquery.js' >  is not working. When I see in console, I can see the message like

```
 "Blocked content from http://mywebsitecom/jquery.js"
```

So, how can I load js and use that?

Answer (score 2):

External files served through HTTP are considered insecure by Google Hangouts, which is served over HTTPS.

You can use [Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) to serve jQuery securely:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Google should point this in their Google+ Hangouts API docs, at least I didn't see where this is mentioned.